# PowerMockito verify that a static method is never called

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am writing a JUnit test to verify that a static method (`MyClass.myMethod()`) is never invoked in the method flow. I tried doing something like this:

```
  PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());
  MyClass.myMethod(Mockito.any());
```

In doing so I receive an UnfinisedVerificationException. How do I test that MyClass.class has no interactions whatsoever in the method execution?

Comment: It turns out that if I place the `PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());` after all method invocations are verified then the test succeeds. Don't understand the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 5):

UnfinishedVerificationException will occur if the Class is not mocked yet but you are trying to verify the invocation of its static method.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
underTest.testMethod();
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());
MyClass.myMethod(Mockito.any());
.
.
.
```

This should succeed if the flow never encounters a call to `MyClass.myMethod()`

Answer (score 5):

I was not able to get this to work using `Mockito.never()`.

I was able to get this to work using an instance of `NoMoreInteractions`.

After calling the production method, and verifying all calls to the static method that was mocked, call `verifyStatic` with an instance of `NoMoreInteractions` as the second argument.

```
mockStatic(MyClassWithStatic.class);
when(MyClassWithStatic.myStaticMethod("foo")).thenReturn(true);

instanceOfClassBeingTested.doIt();

verifyStatic(MyClassWithStatic.class, times(1));
MyClassWithStatic.myStaticMethod("foo");

verifyStatic(MyClassWithStatic.class, new NoMoreInteractions());
MyClassWithStatic.myStaticMethod(Mockito.anyString());
```

If the class being tested calls `myStaticMethod` with anything other than `foo`, the test fails with a message stating that there are unverified invocations.