# PowerMockito verifyStatic: validating async call to static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, completable-future, powermockito

I'm making call to an external system via a `static` method

```
MyExternalServiceAccessor.myMethod(param1, param2);
```

And so far I've been [unit-testing above using `PowerMockito`'s `verifyStatic`](https://import%20static%20org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;%20import%20static%20org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyStatic;) as follows

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyStatic;
..

mockStatic(MyExternalServiceAccessor.class);

..

verifyStatic();
MyExternalService.myMethod(eq(arg1), eq(arg2));
```

---

I now want to make above call 'async' (*best-effort* call with *fire-and-forget* semantics, I don't care for the response); so taking reference from [here](https://sumantmishra.medium.com/java-asynchronous-process-using-completablefuture-755f08d98106) I wrapped it inside `CompletableFuture.runAsync(..)` as follows

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    MyExternalServiceAccessor.myMethod(param1, param2);
});
```

But with this change as expected the unit-test has become flaky because due to the async invocation of `MyExternalServiceAccessor.myMethod(..)`, sometimes validation fails with following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Wanted but not invoked com.company.team.service.serviceutils.MyClass.myFunctionBeingUnitTested(
    null,
    null
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

---

- I'm aware that `Mockito` supports [*verification with timeout*](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.7.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#22) for *non-`static`* methods; is there a `PowerMockito` (or `Mockito`) equivalent of the same for `static` methods?
- If not then what are the alternatives? Can I cleverly rewrite my code and tests in a way to keep it async while still having unit-tests pass everytime?

Comment: One suggestion i got was to instead use `ExecutorService` for parallelization so that we can leverage [`MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService()`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#newDirectExecutorService()) for unit-tests (which will then run sequentially). While it certainly works, I don't want to do it because then effectively we run async computation in production while our unit-tests use synchronous computation, so such tests won't be very confident-inspiring.

Comment: I also had a similar idea to try to somehow override the behaviour of `CompletableFuture.runAsync(..)` for tests so as to effectively make the underlying computation synchronous

Comment: When you use `CompletableFuture.runAsync(…)` without specifying an executor, the [default Fork/Join pool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()) will be used. In that case, your unit test can use [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(your own timeout)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#awaitQuiescence(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to wait for all asynchronous jobs to complete, before checking whether the expected methods have been invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I might've found a fix by using *a non-static method call being made after my static method call* as a 'proxy' for hinting that our static method call must've also happened

I was logging an error metric in case my static method call fails as follows

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        MyExternalServiceAccessor.myMethod(param1, param2);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        // here metricLogger is injected into MyClass from outside so can be mocked for tests
        metricLogger.logCounter("MyExternalServiceAccessor.myMethod:failure", 1);
    }
});
```

Now in above code

- `metricLogger.logCounter(..)` call is a non-static call for which we can leverage mockito's [verification with timeout](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.7.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#22)
- and since it occurs *after* our static `MyExternalServiceAccessor.myMethod(..)` call so we can be sure that if `logCounter` call has happened then `myMethod` call must've also happened

  - *although above statement is true only when we are unit-testing an error scenario where `myMethod` throws an exception*

Therefore for an error scenario we write our test like this for waiting 100ms  before validating that expected methods invoked

```
verify(mockMetricLogger, timeout(100).times(1)).logCounter(eq("MyExternalServiceAccessor.myMethod:failure"), eq(1));
verifyStatic();
MyExternalService.myMethod(eq(arg1), eq(arg2));
```

And for non-error scenario we can use the trick suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64460897/3679900) to wait-and-verify that our mock was called 'zero' times, i.e., not called even after waiting

```
verify(mockMetricLogger, timeout(100).times(0)).logCounter(eq("MyExternalServiceAccessor.myMethod:failure"), eq(1));
verifyStatic();
MyExternalService.myMethod(eq(arg1), eq(arg2));
```

So far my tests have been passing, but since (a) they were not too flaky to begin with and (b) we're dealing with notorious async issues that can show up intermittently, I'm not certain if for non-error scenarios the flakiness has been completely eliminated or not.

*(I can of course completely do away with the flakiness for example by also publishing a counter metric in success scenario and using that as a proxy, but don't want to do that just yet)*

###### UPDATE-1

I also had to test out the scenario where this entire block of async code is never called (due to upstream conditional expressions preventing flow from reaching up till this point where async block is triggered)

For that I leveraged `Mockito.never()` as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50255565/3679900)

```
verify(mockMetricLogger, timeout(100).times(0)).logCounter(eq("MyExternalServiceAccessor.myMethod:failure"), eq(1));
verifyStatic(never());
MyExternalService.myMethod(eq(arg1), eq(arg2));
```